# $\ell$-adic Eilenberg-MacLane space and Brown representability

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, at.algebraic-topology, ct.category-theory, grothendieck-topology

I posted the following question on MathStackexchange, where it was suggested that I should move my question to Mathoverflow, which do here (https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3550741/algebraic-geometric-analogue-of-browns-representability). In topology, the Brown representability theorem is very useful to show for instance that the functor $X\rightarrow H^i(X,A)$ is representable. My question is whether or not there exists an algebraic geometric analogue of the (pointed) homotopy category of CW complexes and of Brown's representability theorem. I would like to use this to show the existence of an $\ell$-adic analogue of the Eilenberg-MacLane space, i.e. to show the functor
$$X\rightarrow H^i_{ét}(X,\mathbb{Q}_{\ell})$$
is representable.

Comment: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/242660/representability-of-weil-cohomology-theories-in-stable-motivic-homotopy-theory